# EC2 telnet username and password

Tags: amazon-ec2, telnet

When connecting to an EC2 instance with telnet what would be the username and password?

I'm using Ubuntu and I didn't set any credentials

Anyway to disable the authentication via telnet?

Comment: Did you install telnet?

Comment: Yep. I tried to connect (telnet ip port) its asking for login and password

Comment: Do you have an account on the server which has a password?

Comment: Also did you know the NSA can see everything you type with telnet?

Comment: I did not create any account. I used the default Ubuntu 18.04 image.

Comment: Lol I'm cool with the NSA

Comment: Okay well if it's asking for a username and password then you need a username and password which means you need an account that has a username and password. The default ec2-user account has no password.

Comment: The other guys at the coffee shop wi-fi can also see everything you type (including your username and password)

Comment: Good  I like how I'm scared now

Comment: (the long story short is telnet is pretty stupid and you should use ssh if you're not stupid)